# How do I change the language in the ui-grid menu JS?

Tags: javascript, angular-ui-grid

I am using ui-grid in rtl. and I want to replace all the caption. Do someone knew how to do it?

[image]

I want to change the text in the marked parts

Comment: How would you do it outside the ui-grid menu JS?

Comment: You should look into i18nService; see [the tutorial](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/Tutorial:%20104%20i18n), including a demo.